# how to upload multiple file in in angular without using plugins like ng2-file uploader

Tags: angular7

want to upload multiple file in same Form using differnt Form controls except ng2 file uploader.

I get multiple file uploader in single form control ,but i want to upload multiple file in different form control in same form
component.html

````
[uploader]="uploader" formControlName="imageUpload" multiple  />
      <td nowrap>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs
     (click)="item.upload()" [disabled]="item.isReady || item.isUploading || item.isSuccess">
     <span ></span> Upload </button> 
 <button type="button"s"
    (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
     <span></span> Upload all</button>
                            ```
component.ts
```public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL,authToken:`Bearer ${this.Token}` });
  public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
  public hasAnotherDropZoneOver:boolean = false;

  public fileOverBase(e:any):void {
    this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
  }

  public fileOverAnother(e:any):void {
    this.hasAnotherDropZoneOver = e;
  }```
````

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code / efforts

Comment: I shared my code.